# Disabling ContrastEnhancement in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, sld

I am using Geoserver to upload and display GTiff images in OpenLayers. The images are unsigned 16 bit grayscale at about 300MB size and are processed to to give better performance using the methods [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/data.html).

When viewing the images in OpenLayers it changes darkness when zooming in/out and from what I understand this is coming from the ContrastEnhancement property in the style script (SLD).

This is not necessary with the images I have and are only lowering the performance.

Is it possible to disable this altogether?

Changing from *Normalize* to *Histogram* in SLD makes it better, but now black values for some reason will be treated as no-value and become transparent when zooming in.

I am fairly new with GeoServer.

Comment: As you can see from http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/symbolizers/raster.html contrast enhancement is not required. Cut if off and it is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I have tried to remove the ContrastEnhancement tag with no effect. If it's removed then you get the same effect as with Normalize, so it seems like that is the default.