# Degradation of the quality of a raster after publishing to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, gdal, openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to publish a satellite raster (.tif) into GeoServer and display it in a web application using OpenLayers. I tried to use many procedures but without any good results.
This is the original raster : [image: original raster]
I tiled the raster and made a TileWMS call here is the result : [image]
If I make a Image call :

[image]

This is the result of gdalinfo if it helps :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: image.tif
  Size is 11517, 13539
  Coordinate System is:
  PROJCS["IMAGINE GeoTIFF Support
  ERDAS IMAGINE 2018  16.5.0.376
  Projection = Lambert Conformal Conic",
      GEOGCS["Merchich",
          DATUM["Merchich",
              SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (IGN)",6378249.2,293.4660212936265,
                  AUTHORITY["EPSG","7011"]],
              AUTHORITY["EPSG","6261"]],
          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
          UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","4261"]],
      PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",34.86645766666667],
      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",31.72392566666667],
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",33.3],
      PARAMETER["central_meridian",-5.4],
      PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
      PARAMETER["false_northing",300000],
      UNIT["metre",1,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
  Origin = (797632.239454125985503,491944.985518844972830)
  Pixel Size = (0.512510120364827,-0.512510120364827)
  Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
    TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=2018
    TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=1
    TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
    TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IMAGINE TIFF Support
  Copyright 1991 - 1999 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved
  @(#)$RCSfile: etif.c $ $Revision: 1.10.1.9.1.9.2.11 $ $Date: 2004/09/15 18:42:01EDT $
    TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
    TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
  Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (  797632.239,  491944.986) (  2d 8'23.51"W, 34d59'20.20"N)
  Lower Left  (  797632.239,  485006.111) (  2d 8'32.05"W, 34d55'35.15"N)
  Upper Right (  803534.819,  491944.986) (  2d 4'30.91"W, 34d59'14.16"N)
  Lower Right (  803534.819,  485006.111) (  2d 4'39.62"W, 34d55'29.11"N)
  Center      (  800583.529,  488475.548) (  2d 6'31.52"W, 34d57'24.67"N)
  Band 1 Block=11517x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
    NoData Value=2.13054804926827954e-53
  Band 2 Block=11517x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    NoData Value=2.13054804926827954e-53
  Band 3 Block=11517x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    NoData Value=2.13054804926827954e-53
  Band 4 Block=11517x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
    NoData Value=2.13054804926827954e-53
```

EDIT :
The question was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287404/disabling-contrastenhancement-in-geoserver) one but I don't think it is because I don't know if we have the same problem, since the other post doesn't contain more details

Comment: The image you are uploading is a 4-band 16-bit .tiff file. Can you confirm that the resolution of the layer you created in openlayers is the same? You can use the method getMaxResolution() within Openlayers (ol/layer/Image~ImageLayer).

Comment: I don't think it's caused by Openlayers because even if display it in geoserver it gives the same result. This is max resolution in Openlayers 156367.7919628329

Comment: I tried to add a SLD style to the published raster and solved the problem. The SLD allow to perform contrast enhancement